# Angular in Kubernetes failing to pull image

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I created an image and pushed to dockerHub, from an angular project. I can see that if I will go to localhost:80 it will open the portal. This are the steps:

```
ng build
docker build -t tiberiu1234/template:v1 .
docker run -rm -d -p 80:80 tiberiu1234/template:v1
```

Now I tried to do the same thing but in kubernetes. I created deployment and service and trigger it using the same image:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: portal-deployment
  labels:
    app: portal
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: portal
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: portal
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: portal
        image: tiberiu1234/portal:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: portal-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: portal
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

Now If I will go and check I will see:

```
portal-deployment                        0/3     3            0           4m1s
portal-service                                     ClusterIP      10.2.0.114   <none>         80/TCP                       3m56s

portal-deployment-67c6d9bb6c-88cvn                        0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          23m
portal-deployment-67c6d9bb6c-jrmjz                        0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          23m
portal-deployment-67c6d9bb6c-wm65h                        0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          23m
```

**Error is:**
kubectl logs -f portal-deployment-67c6d9bb6c-88cvn
Error from server (BadRequest): container "portal" in pod "portal-deployment-67c6d9bb6c-88cvn" is waiting to start: **trying and failing to pull image**  and I don't understand why, can you help me with this?

Comment: I saw that edit: is `ImagePullPolicy` actually part of the deployment?

Comment: no is not part of the deployment

Comment: It appears that your images are private on Docker hub. Have you [configured your docker hub credentials](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)?

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/tiberiu1234/template1 is a public repository, and I am login to dockerHub locally

Comment: Please, remove 'angular' tag, as this questions is not related to angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your repository is private and requires login to pull image.

You need to create a registry credentials secret for kubernetes, as it do not uses docker credentials.

See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

1. Create a secret named regcred:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=<your-registry-server> --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>
```

2. Then use this secret in your deployment descriptor:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
...
spec:
  ...
  template:
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
    ...
```